# D3 time scale axis ticks are irregular on year boundaries

Tags: d3.js

**UPDATE:** The [bl.ocks.org example](http://bl.ocks.org/benkimball/8570073) has been updated with the solution.

Is it possible to make the default tick generator for a time scale axis ignore month and year boundaries when calculating tick positions?

As seen in [this bl.ocks.org example](http://bl.ocks.org/benkimball/8570073), when a D3 time scale axis with day ticks spans the end of a year, the default tick generator sometimes draws ticks with irregular spacing. This code (also in the gist above) result in an axis with ticks spaced every two days except for December 31 and January 1, which are both drawn, resulting in an irregular appearance. I've highlighted the undesirable tick labels in red.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  p { width: 600px; margin-bottom: 30px; }
  .chart { shape-rendering: crispEdges; }
  .axis text { font: 10px sans-serif; }
  .axis line, .axis path { fill: none; stroke: black; }
</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var start_date = "2013-12-21T00:00:00Z",
    end_date   = "2014-01-07T00:00:00Z",
    iso        = d3.time.format.iso,
    t1         = iso.parse(start_date),
    t2         = iso.parse(end_date),

var margin = {top: 0, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 10},
    width  = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 100 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([t1, t2])
    .range([0, width])

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("class", "chart")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'x axis')
    .call(xAxis)
  .selectAll('text')
    .attr('fill', function(d) { if(is_problematic(d)) { return "red"; } })

function is_problematic(d) {
  return ((d.getDate() == 31) || (d.getDate() == 1));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you explicitly set the tick values, you'll avoid the weird end of the year rounding issue:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .tickValues(d3.time.days(t1, t2).filter(function(d, i){ return !(i % 2); }))
```

[fixed](http://bl.ocks.org/1wheel/8571405/3ea0c32599811cde891dcf6be5c0f863bfdd7664)

Comment: Thanks Adam. I forgot to mention in my question that I'd like the same code to handle series of different lengths. If I display every other label by overriding the default tickValues, the axis will get too crowded when there are, say, 100 days displayed. I'm hoping to somehow preserve the existing label culling behavior.

Comment: Your answer led me to my solution, which was to calculate how many intervals I needed to skip between labels. Since I know the width of a label, and I know the width of the chart, I used `var max_label_count = width / LABEL_WIDTH, var label_skip = Math.ceil(interval.range(t1, t2).length / max_label_count)` and then substituted `label_skip` for `2` in your solution.